# How can I prevent images flickering using setInterval() in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, transition, setinterval

Jquery:

```
var count = 3;

setInterval(function() {
    if (count == 12) {
        count = 3;
    }

    count++;
    $('.desktop').css({'background-image': 'url(images/index_main_bg'+count+'.jpg)'});
}, 3000);
```

CSS:

```
.desktop {
    background: url(images/index_main_bg4.jpg) center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    z-index: 9;
    transition: background 1.1s linear;
}
```

Basically, I just want these background images to have a smooth transition but it has a delayed flicker at seemingly random times.  Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: you could try preloading the images, so the moment you define them as backgrounds they are already in the browsers cache, ready to draw. check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery

Comment: Use a big image containing all the images and then change the background positions(sprite images), or start animation after all the images are loaded

Answer (score 0):

Create multiple '.desktop' elements and assign different background for all. You can just show and hide (or any animation of your requirement) particular .desktop element. You wont see flickering with this solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I actually have a lot of content in the div with class ".desktop".  But this lead me to a similar approach:  I created multiple classes such as .desktop2, .desktop3, etc. with these different background images.  I then used addClass() and removeClass().

Comment: Cool. You can optimize the code by keeping one common class. Like desktopGeneralClass and remove active class from one desktopGeneralClass and add active to next desktopGeneralClass. by doing this way, you do not have to write javascript code in case if you had more images to carousel.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up doing:

Jquery:

```
var count=3;

setInterval(function() {
    if(count==11){
        $('#desktop').removeClass('desktop'+(count+1));
        count=3;
        $('#desktop').addClass('desktop'+(count+1));
    } else {
        count++;
        $('#desktop').removeClass('desktop'+count);
        $('#desktop').addClass('desktop'+(count+1));
    }
}, 3000);
```

CSS (I created multiple classes which are added and removed):

```
.desktop4 {
  background-image: url(images/index_main_bg4.jpg);
}

.desktop5 {
  background-image: url(images/index_main_bg5.jpg);
}

.desktop6 {
  background-image: url(images/index_main_bg6.jpg);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="desktop" class="desktop4">
   SOME CONTENT
<div>
```

This avoided the flickering instead of changing the style of a particular class as before.

Answer (score -1):

Use a big image containing all the images and then change the background positions(sprite images)

```js
var count = 1,varx_pos = 0;
setInterval(function(){
 varx_pos += 180;
 if(count == 3){varx_pos = 0;count=0;}
  $('.desktop').css({'background-position-x':varx_pos+'px'});
 count++;
},150);
```

```css
.desktop{
background-image:url('http://spritely.net/images/bird_180x180.png');
width:180px;
height:120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="desktop"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  This seems like a more compact approach than using addClass() and removeClass() on a bunch of classes with different background images...which is what I ended up doing.  I was not sure how to create the "big image" containing all images as you mentioned?